# Notifications from BLE characteristics not printing

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to get the output from the Masimo MightySat by BLE.

When I scan for the services of the device this is the output, I have kept in some of the comments I made on the output when testing different services and characteristics in case that is helpful.

```
INFO:__main__:Connected: True
INFO:__main__:[Service] 54c21000-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5 (Handle: 19): Unknown

    # Characteristic gives error: "Bluetooth command failed (code: 3, error: Attribute can't be written)"
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 54c21001-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5 (write-without-response), Value: None, Type: <class 'NoneType'>
    # Hanging, maybe accessing this information but notifcation handler issue, investigate
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 54c21002-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5 (notify), Value: None, Type: <class 'NoneType'>
INFO:__main__:          [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 24): Client Characteristic Configuration) | Value: b'\x00\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
INFO:__main__:[Service] 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 8): Generic Attribute Profile
INFO:__main__:[Service] 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 9): Device Information
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (read), Value: b'2126602184', Type: <class 'bytes'>
INFO:__main__:          [Descriptor] 00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 18): Characteristic Presentation Format) | Value: b'\x19\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (read), Value: b'Masimo', Type: <class 'bytes'>
INFO:__main__:          [Descriptor] 00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 15): Characteristic Presentation Format) | Value: b'\x19\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
=
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (read), Value: b'MightySat\x00\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
INFO:__main__:          [Descriptor] 00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 12): Characteristic Presentation Format) | Value: b'\x19\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
        
    # First characteristic gives error: "Bluetooth command failed (code: 3, error: Attribute can't be written)"
INFO:__main__:[Service] 00001822-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 25): Pulse Oximeter
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a60-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (read), Value: b'C\x00\xe0\xc10\x04\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
    
INFO:__main__:  [Characteristic] 00002a5e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (indicate), Value: None, Type: <class 'NoneType'>
INFO:__main__:          [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 30): Client Characteristic Configuration) | Value: b'\x00\x00', Type: <class 'bytes'>
```

Scanning based on the information provided by ukBaz provided this:

[image: Result of nRF connect]

I wrote this code based on various pieces online:

```
from bluepy import btle

class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        # ... initialise here

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        print("\n- handleNotification -\n")
        print(data)
        # ... perhaps check cHandle
        # ... process 'data'


# Initialisation  -------

print("Connecting to Masimo")
p = btle.Peripheral("FA:F5:3B:2B:7D:00", "random")
print("Connted to Masimo successfully, delegate setup")

p.setDelegate( MyDelegate() )

notif_on = b"\0x1\x00"

# Setup to turn notifications on, e.g.
print("Getting services by ID and handles")
svc = p.getServiceByUUID("54c21000-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5")
# ch = svc.getCharacteristics()[0]
CCCD_UUID = 0x2902
ch = svc.getCharacteristics("54c21002-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5")[0]
ch_cccd = ch.getDescriptors(forUUID=CCCD_UUID)[0]
ch_cccd.write(notif_on)

setup_data = b'\x00\x00'

print("Writing characteristics")
p.writeCharacteristic(24, setup_data, withResponse=True)
# # Main loop --------

while True:
    if p.waitForNotifications(1.0):
        # handleNotification() was called
        continue

    print("Waiting...")
    # Perhaps do something else here
```

When I run it this is the output I get:

```
Connecting to Masimo
Connted to Masimo successfully, delegate setup
Getting services by ID and handles
Service <uuid=54c21000-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5 handleStart=19 handleEnd=24>
Characteristic <54c21001-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5>, hnd=0x14, supports WRITE NO RESPONSE 
Characteristic <54c21002-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5>, hnd=0x16, supports NOTIFY 
Services and handles collected
Initialising setup data
Setup data initialised
Writing characteristics
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
```

And then it just hangs, repeating the "Waiting..." infinitely.

I'd appreciate any help possible here as BLE is a bit confusing for me at the moment.

Thanks!

Interestingly no information is sent whilst it's being worn via the pulse oximeter; however, when it is removed it sends just the pulse and oxygen saturation, not the remaining datatypes.

[image: scanner output 2]

Comment: I don't see you writing to the `0x2902` descriptor at all to start the notifications so I suspect that is why you are not getting any. A user had a similar issue logged in the pybluez repo which got resolved: https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/468#issuecomment-1003418227

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and get back with results in the morning!

Comment: @ukBaz I made the changes suggested by yourself and have edited the code snippet to show that and I am getting this error instead:

list index out of range
  File "/home/me/Software/locallyHeld/project/subfolder/bluetooth/masimoBluepy.py", line 31, in <module>
    ch_cccd = ch.getDescriptors(forUUID=CCCD_UUID)[0]

Comment: The notify seems to be on characteristic `54c21002-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5` and not `54c21001-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5` that you appear to be using to get the descriptor. Could that be the issue?  It looks like the device is expecting commands to be sent to `54c21001` and will give responses (notifications) on `54c21002`. Are you sure your `writeCharacteristic` command is correct? Handle: 24 seems to be the handle of the notification descriptor. Is writing zero to it turning the notifications off again?

Comment: Hi @ukBaz so I think we (you, I am just the typewriting monkey) are getting somewhere. I changed to `54c21002` as suggested, and that gets back to waiting.

I am in no way sure my `writeCharacteristic` is correct it could be wrong. I changed the `setup_data` to `setup_data=b'\x01\x00'` and that still hung on waiting. This is all really new to me, what should I be looking for on the `writeCharacteristic`?

Comment: The value of the UUID show that it is device/manufacturer specific information that is being transmitted so there is no way I can know what to send or will be received. If it is not documented, then you will have to reverse engineer what the manufacturer's app does. Before you get to that stage using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) can sometimes be helpful to work out what the device is doing without worrying about your code.

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for the info on that app, I really appreciate it.

Scanning that seems to indicate that I might have been beating down the wrong service and I should have been looking at `00001822-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` as the service; however, they have properties READ and INDICATE only which caused an error before, so I will beat down that door a little!

Comment: @ukBaz I've added the image result from the scan. I'll keep trying but if you do get any more ideas I would really appreciate it but I know I have taken a lot of your time!

Comment: As you are now looking at Bluetooth SIG adopted characteristics they are documented at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/ . It is the Assigned Numbers Document and GATT Specification Supplement that will be of most use to you.

Comment: It seems the Pulse Oximeter Service characteristics are documented in:  https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/pulse-oximeter-service-1-0-1/

Comment: @ukBaz I will admit I can't make heads nor tails of that but I know enough to know you've put me on the right path! Thank you!

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for all your help. I think that I have discovered the issue.

I have two oximeters, one very cheap, and one the Masimo. When I compared the app you recommended for the pair of them, the cheap one is broadcasting the data along the notify channel, there are a constant stream of messages. When I look with the Masimo, no information is being sent along those channels for any service.

Comment: @ukBaz I am fairly sure this just means I am out of luck here right? I need to write something to the `54c21000-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5` to be able to connect and start reading/receiving data from along the channels `54c21002-a720-4b4f-11e4-9fe20002a5d5`, but that could be anything so that's me up against the wall?

Comment: I suspect not. In the nRF app when you are connected to the Masimo device, there should be an icon which is multiple down arrows for the `0x2a5e` characteristic. Click on that and it should start the notifications. This is the same as you sending `b"\x01\x00"` to the `0x2902` UUID Descriptor of the `0x2a5e` Characteristic in the Python code.  It might be that one device has notifications turned on by default and one doesn't.

Comment: @ukBaz Yeah, unfortunately I have done that and the "Value" changes to "Indications enabled" on `0x2A5E` and receives no data like the other oximeter, just stays on that. Similarly on the other long UUID `54c21002` when I hit the three arrows pointing at me value switches to "Notifications enabled" but no values come through.

Comment: Probably need to look at `PLX Features` (`0x2a60`) to see what features are enabled on that device.

Comment: @ukBaz I've added another image to the bottom. When I remove the device it seems like it's sending the data for the pulse oximeter parts (pulse rate and blood oxygen) but not sending the other data it records (respiratory rate etc). Nothing ever comes from the other service. Would this perhaps mean it is live broadcasting over that channel to the app if used? Do you have any idea how I might get the remaining info?